Making a numbered list
I am attempting to insert some coding into an excel macro I have. In short, the macro has one sheet where you paste data from an external source, click a macro button, and on another sheet it does conversions and calculations as needed. It's reused, but the coding is a one time action. What I want it to do is to look at a specific range in a column (i.e. B3:B96), that will be a text input, and have the VBA coding sequentially assign a numeric value to a blank column specified (i.e. C3:C96). But, if a value is repeated from the input, it will assign the same number to that same. The input coming in is always different and isn't set. The repeated values, if present, will be random and at a different place each time the macro is used, and not always happen, but will most of the time.
Here's an example of what I want it to do. In the table below, column A is the input from the and Column B is what I want as the output. If column A is blank, I want column B to also be blank.



Column A
Column B




Value 1
1


Value 2
2


Value 2
2


Value 3
3


Value 4
4


Value 4
4


Value 5
5



The maximum number this is going to reach is 90. This subsection of code is also going to be placed inside a group of other coding.
I am relatively new to VBA, and am not a programmer by trade or education. This macro is used for scientific data analysis. I don't have anything I tried before, because I don't know if what I am requesting is possible in VBA or not.
Thank you for any assistance you can give.

Create Simple Integer IDs For Unique Values in Column

Sub CreateIDsTEST()
    
    Const SHEET_NAME As String = "Sheet1"
    Const SRC_TOP_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "B3"
    Const DST_COLUMN As String = "C"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets(SHEET_NAME)
    
    CreateIDs ws, SRC_TOP_CELL_ADDRESS, DST_COLUMN
    
    ' Or instead of all of the previous, simply:
    'CreateIDs ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1"), "B3", "C"

End Sub

Sub CreateIDs( _
        ws As Worksheet, _
        SourceTopCellAddress As String, _
        DestinationColumn As String)
    
    Dim rg As Range, rCount As Long
    
    With ws.Range(SourceTopCellAddress)
        rCount = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp).Row - .Row + 1
        If rCount < 1 Then
            MsgBox "No data!", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Set rg = .Resize(rCount)
    End With
    
    Dim Data() As Variant
    If rCount = 1 Then
        ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = rg.Value
    Else
        Data = rg.Value
    End If

    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim sr As Long, dr As Long, rStr As String
    
    For sr = 1 To rCount
        rStr = CStr(Data(sr, 1))
        If Not dict.Exists(rStr) Then
            dr = dr + 1
            dict(rStr) = dr
        End If
        Data(sr, 1) = dict(rStr)
    Next sr
    
    rg.EntireRow.Columns(DestinationColumn).Value = Data

    MsgBox "IDs created.", vbInformation
    
End Sub


Thank you! I actually didn't know about the Unique function, and since I have a sheet doing other excel functions, I used that so that I didn't need to add any coding to my VBA, but thank you again for your time and answer.


Apply formula on B1, and fill down

=MATCH(A1, UNIQUE($A$1:A1), 0)

OR

=MATCH(A1, UNIQUE($A:$A), 0)



Thank you! I didn't know this function could be done right on the sheet. I incorporated it and it worked like a charm, thanks!
